# Pass sql data into associative array in PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, associative-array

I am trying to print out some database entries into an associative array, but it's only printing the first entry.

This is my code

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $data_array = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $data_array['name']=$row["name"];
        $data_array['title']=$row["title"];
        $date=date_create($row['published']);
        $edited_date=date_format($date,"l, F d, Y");
        $data_array['date']=$edited_date; 
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
} 
echo json_encode($data_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're replacing the data each time. You need to add more depth to your array:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $data_array[]['name']=$row["name"];
    $data_array[]['title']=$row["title"];
    $date=date_create($row['published']);
    $edited_date=date_format($date,"l, F d, Y");
    $data_array[]['date']=$edited_date; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my day, you're my hero :)

Comment: One day I'll also be someone's hero.